# Prove that there exists an infinitely many primes $p$ such that $p \mid f(n_p)$ but $p^2 \nmid f(n_p)$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, contest-math

This is the question I saw on the competition math session the other day, however, the solution was not given.

$f(x)\in \mathbb{Z}[x]$ is a non-constant irreducible polynomial. Does there exist infinitely many primes $p$ for which there always exists a positive integer $n_p$ such that $p\mid f(n_p)$ but $p^2 \nmid f(n_p)$?

My naive guess is yes, but I have no idea about its proof.

Answer (score 2):

First apply the standard argument to get infinitely many primes such that $f$ has a root $\bmod p$: for $n$ large $f(n)\sim cn^d$ which is impossible if the prime factors of $f(n)$ are taken in a finite set.

Then discard from this set $S$ of infinitely many primes the finitely many primes dividing the discriminant $Disc(f)$.

For each $p\in S$, we have $p | f(n_p)$ and $p\nmid f'(n_p)$.
Check that $f(n_p+p) = f(n_p)+p f'(n_p)+p^2 r_p$.

So one of $n_p, n_p+p$ is a root $\bmod p$ but not $\bmod p^2$.

Comment: Sorry, I'm totally new to elementary number theory stuff. Forgive me if I ask trivial, dumb questions. Why is $f(n)~cn^d$ impossible if the prime factors are taken in a finite set? Also, how is the discriminant related to the second part?

Comment: @friendOfMath If $f(n_p)=f'(n_p)=0\bmod p$ then the discriminant of $f\bmod p$ is $0$ ie. $p$ divides the discriminant of $f$. Given a finite set of $k$ primes, at most $2\log_2(n)^k$ integers $\in [-n,n]$ have their prime factors in this set, not enough for $f$ taking more than $\frac1{2c} n^{1/d}$ distinct values in $[-n,n]$.